# How can I hide all "someone likes something" updates?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to hide all the "someone likes something" updates on facebook, but I don't want to block those people, as I still want to see status updates, pictures, shared links, and all else.

I just don't what to see what my friends like, and the compulsive "like" from some of them fills up my news feed. All else, ok, but I don't want to see these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use extension like [FBPurity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) to do that.

Comment: I was expecting on an official solution, but I just tried this extension, and works great! Thanks nanda!

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe it is possible. You can hide the person completely, but not just their likes. I know you can hide individual apps without affecting the person, but it looks like facebook does not treat "likes" as a separate app.

Answer (score -1):

You can now hide individual posts, so if you do this enough, Facebook will probably figure out you don't like these stories