# Making Facebook Less Annoying

Tags: facebook

I rejoined Facebook recently (quite sadly).

What are some ways to keep the Like Button, What Kind Of? Applications, <3<3<3<3<3<3<3 girls, spamspamspam guys, and just the general kind of stuff that makes Facebook suck?

Answer (score 4):

From the browser interface, hover your cursor over a post that you don't want to see.   An [X] will appear at the upper right corner.   Click the X, and you will be given a choice to hide posts by that user, the application, or page that created the post.   You'll have to do this for each application that annoys you.

Probably more importantly, don't friend people and pages unless you genuinely want to see what they are posting!

Edit: see [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/how-can-i-hide-all-someone-likes-something-updates) for a plugin approach

Answer (score 2):

I'm very fond of [FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/).  It hides all of the third-party apps by default, and you can turn on or off individual apps, or via a text filter.  The maintainer is also very quick about updating it in response to facebook changes.